# How to use two different json data files as per environment in cypress

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress

I have a specific requirement to use two different data files per environment (stage.json & prod.json) in such a way that when I use stage env, data should come from stage.json & when I use prod env, data should come from prod.json. I have created a framework in Cypress using Mocha. I checked tutorials of Cypress but could not find relevant information. I also googled out but no luck. I would appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration)

> **Change Configuration File**
>
> You can change the configuration file or turn off the use of a configuration file by using the --config-file flag.
>
> ```js
> cypress open --config-file <config-file>
> ```

So, have your staging in `cypress.json` then to run prod call `cypress run --config-file prod.json`.

Answer (score 1):

What about using plain JS :

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
// do dev stuff
} 
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
//do production stuff
}
```

I guess you could find a trick, based on this logic, to differenciate staging from prod. I don't think that Cypress itself could handle that.

I hope this could help

Comment: Thanks, but I have special requirement to run the tests periodically in stage & one time in prod whenever required so in that case I need to just change env variable & want to run tests